# Change the direction of animation

Tags: html, css, animate.css, wow.js

I am using `wow.js` with `animate.js` to show animation on mouse scroll.

I want to change the direction of animation on small device like on large screen it should animate from right and on small device it should animate from bottom.

Here is a snippet to show what I need.

```js
new WOW().init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <section class="wow fadeInRight" >Section 1</section>
  <section class="wow fadeInUp"  data-wow-delay="1s">Section 1 on mobile</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you don't have to use two content for this , just use one element and change animation class for mobile.
You can reduce the content.**

**I just add a media query to change the the animation class from** `anime.min.css`

> **You can change the Media Query Value(767px)**

```js
new WOW().init();
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .anim-mob-up.fadeInRight {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft !important;
    animation-name: fadeInLeft !important; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section class="wow fadeInRight anim-mob-up">Section 1 Both Desk & Mobile</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do this:

```js
new WOW().init();
```

```css
.desktop {
  display: block;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width:767px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="wow fadeInRight desktop">Section 1</section>
<section class="wow fadeInUp mobile">Section 1 on mobile</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove class `fadeInRight` from your html.
2. Detect screen width using JS.
3. If it less or equal to 1024, add `fadeInUp` to element, otherwise add `fadeInRight` to element.

```js
  const wow = document.querySelectorAll('.wow')
  const dir = window.innerWidth <= 1024 ? 'fadeInUp' : 'fadeInRight'
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(wow, el => el.classList.add(dir))

new WOW().init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <section class="wow" >Section 1</section>
  <section class="wow"  data-wow-delay="1s">Section 1 on mobile</section>
```